# How to join 3 sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, union

I just started learning MySQL, and I've got 3 very similar tables in the same database.
For example:

```
table name: shoes
id (int, primary key)
name (varchar)

table name: t-shirts
id (int, primary key)
name (varchar)

table name: skirts
id (int, primary key)
name (varchar)
```

There's an administration page where I can add a new product, and there's a select form also so I can manage which table it is going into.

Comment: What exactly is your question now? You are just stating that you have three different tables. How would you want them to be displayed?

Comment: I've got 3 tables in the same database, although they have the very same construction, they are independent from each other. Thing is, I need one query, where it is the easiest if I merge them, like they were in 1 table. Since all 3 tables got the same field names (id, and name), but totally different values (there aren't two product ids with the value "2", etc), I thought this could be done easily. I hope you understand now.

Comment: Okay, so you just want a list of all "products"? Then my answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's OK now, works like a charm. Sorry for my dumbness. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show all entries of all three tables you can just do

```
(SELECT * FROM shoes) UNION 
(SELECT * FROM tshirt) UNION 
(SELECT * FROM skirts);
```

Note: UNION only works on structurally identical tables (i.e. the same number of attributes).